# What does this Executor summary mean

Tags: apache-spark

Could you please explain **in detail** what each of these metrics mean for the job that I ran with this command and how it all co relates

```
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class com.classname --num-executors 300 --executor-cores 5 --driver-cores 5 --executor-memory 64G --driver-memory 64G --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0
```

[image]

Comment: These might be helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNpzrkB5KQQ&ab_channel=AdvancingAnalytics and https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-web-ui-understanding/?expand_article=1